# AppDomain.DoCallBack returns System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Tags: c#

I keep getting
    `An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'
    occurred in IRCBot.exe but was not handled in user code`
from AppDomain.DoCallBack

My code is

```
            object result = null;
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting to run in sandbox");
            sandbox.DoCallBack(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Creating thread");
                try
                {
                    var scriptThread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Trying");
                            result = CSharpScript.RunAsync(code).ReturnValue.Result;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            result = ex.Message;
                        }
                    });
                    scriptThread.Start();

                    if (!scriptThread.Join(6000))
                    {
                        scriptThread.Abort();
                        AppDomain.Unload(sandbox);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex.ToString();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = e.ToString();
        }
```

Sorry if this question sounded brief, but I don't really know what more to say. I have traced down the source of the exception to DoCallBack. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is in "code" variable?

Comment: The code variable is a string, a code snippet to be executed.

Comment: Can give a sample code snippet?

Comment: Any code snippet will do, an example would be "1+1" The main problem is in DoCallBack which runs the code in a sandbox to prevent security issues.

Answer (score 5):

The delegate passed to DoCallback must either represent a static method or a method on a serializable class. The class autogenerated by the C# compiler for the lambda expression isn't serializable. You need to implement the method that should be called on a serializable class yourself, e.g.

```cs
[Serializable]
class CallbackContext
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public void Entry()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating thread");
        try
        {
            var scriptThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Trying");
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("result", CSharpScript.RunAsync(Code).ReturnValue.Result);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("result", ex.Message);
                }
            });
            scriptThread.Start();

            if (!scriptThread.Join(6000))
            {
                scriptThread.Abort();
                AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("result", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

    ...

    object result = null;
    try {
        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to run in sandbox");
        CallbackContext ctx = new CallbackContext();
        ctx.Code = code;
        sandbox.DoCallBack(ctx.Entry);
        result = sandbox.GetData("result");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        result = e.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for including how to return a result.  By the way, I believe you can also use `AppDomain.SetData` to pass in parameters, but this is unnecessary if using a class that is serialized into the second AppDomain.

Comment: In unity those code trigger assembly not found exception, it failed to find the assembly contains class CallbackContext, don't know how to fix it. try to put the assembly to GAC, same exception occurs.